# Is there a way to constrain what types are allowed to inherit my C# class?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

For my own personal edification--is there any way to do this? I'm implementing an `Imageable` class that provides a `ToWmf()` function that outputs the WPF object to a vector graphic. But this only makes sense for WPF `Visual` types, and so one of the components of the imaging operation requires a parameter with type `Visual`, which I would intend to be `this`.

I've found all kinds of examples of C# parameter constraints but no examples of constraining the inheriting class type. For the time being I'm using a static `ImagingUtil.ToWmf()` class, but is this just a flat-out No answer or is there another way?

Comment: I don't think this makes sense; the purpose of a base class is to enforce a common interface on a bunch of related classes.

Comment: Why would/should anyone want this behaviour?

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your base class should constrain its overriding type using an interface (i.e. a set of abstract methods) you expect it to implement. It seems to me this constraint should be sufficient.

Comment: Well, of course, use the **sealed** keyword.  If you don't have the guts to use it then, no, all your base belong to us.

Comment: Ack...in this case what I really need is [an extension method....](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: Thanks all. In my case an extension method will do and is conceptually what I'm wanting. I should disclose that I really did spend a while searching before asking this question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question implies that the `Imageable` object would also be a `Visual` at the same time (otherwise how are you going to pass `this` to something that needs a `Visual`?).

This is not possible unless one of the two types inherits from the other, and since `Visual` is not under your control then `Imageable` must be a descendant of `Visual`. In which case there is no problem at all.

In all likelihood what you want to be doing is defining an `IImageable` interface and then implementing an extension method that looks like this:

```
public static void ToWmf<T>(this T imageable) where T : Visual, IImageable
{
    // ....
}
```

This way any (and only a) user-defined class that derives from `Visual` and at the same time implements `IImageable` can be processed by `ToWmf`.

Comment: Huh. I mentioned in a different answer that what I needed was an extension method but this will be interesting variation on that and answers my question directly. Thank you, sir

Answer (score 0):

You could use constraints for generics. See [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) here for more info.

```
public interface IImageable<T> where T : Visual
{
    MyReturnType ToWmf();
}

public class MyImageable : IImageable<XXX> // does not work if XXX is not a Visual / inherited from Visual
{
   //implements MyReturnType ToWmf();
}
```

Then just inject IImageable as param.

Comment: ... yes but you can inherit from a generic class/Interface.

Comment: That's what I meant by comment about parameter constraints in my question. Thanks, though.